# C++11 moving one vector to another - passing an rvalue reference to a constructor

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I am trying to understand C++ move semantics, `std::move()` and rvalue references.

I've implemented this example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  int totalSize = 6;

  std::vector<double> oldData{ 10, 20, 30 }; 

  oldData.resize(totalSize, 0);

  std::vector<double> newData(std::move(oldData));
  return 0;
}
```

I'd like to know is this actually moving vector `oldData` to `newData` or is copying happening under the hood.

Comment: The `move` is fine, but think about your loop condition - `oldData.size()` keeps changing.

Comment: how you populate the vector has nothing to do with the ctor and the move. That is just noise that distracts you.

Comment: I concur with the previous comments about your example. A simple call to `std::vector::resize` will do exactly what you set out to do with the `reserve` and loop, only without a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you fix the infinite loop at:

> ```
>   for(unsigned i = 0; i < totalSize - oldData.size(); ++i)
>     oldData.push_back(0);
> ```

And write something like:

```
  for(unsigned i = oldData.size(); i < totalSize; ++i)
    oldData.push_back(0);
```

or, even better:

```
  oldData.resize(totalSize, 0);
```

Then `std::move` will move all the data from `oldData` to `newData`. Here is [a quote from cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector):

> 6) Move constructor. Constructs the container with the contents of
>   other using move semantics. Allocator is obtained by move-construction
>   from the allocator belonging to other. After the move, other is
>   guaranteed to be empty().
>
> 7) Allocator-extended move constructor. Using alloc as the allocator for the new container, moving the contents from other; if alloc != other.get_allocator(), this results in an element-wise move. (in that case, other is not guaranteed to be empty after the move)

In your specific case, the vector has a default allocator, which means that only item (6) applies. However, if someone passes an allocator then things become more interesting.

Here is the rest of cppreference on the subject of **complexity**:

> 6) Constant.
>
> 7) Linear if alloc != other.get_allocator(), otherwise constant.

Again, in your case the complexity is O(1), but with allocators things get more interesting.

**Conclusion**: internal representation has to move a constant number of pointers in O(1), and not move the elements one-by-one. It is possible to implement vector with one pointer with capacity and size integers, or three pointers (begin, end, and the end of capacity). And for all these implementations, moving is a simple playing around with pointers.

However, if a non-default allocator is provided and the two vectors use a different allocator object, then the values have to be moved or copied one-by-one.